# React Redux RTK - run a query when a variable gets value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have 3 queries in RTK which are run when the component is mounted. The data from the first query is passed into the second and third and I use `skip: !isSuccess` for the query to run only when the `data` is available. This works fine.
However, my use-case is slightly different. I wish to take IDs from the `data` in first query to pass to other two queries. If I send the data as is, I have to place `IDs = data.map(row => row.id)` inside the query function, which is run twice since there are two queries using the same data. I wish to extract these IDs before I send to the queries.

Here is how my code looks -

```
# inside the component

const { data, error, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetDataQuery();
const { data: todoData, error: todoError } = useGetCountersQuery({"issueType": "todos", data}, {skip: !isSuccess});
const { data: rmaData, error: rmaError } = useGetCountersQuery({"issueType": "rmas", data}, {skip: !isSuccess})


    if (error) { console.log(error); }

    if (data) {
        if (!data.success){ 
            console.log("failed"); 
        }
    }
```

```
# the query
getCounters: build.query({
            query: ({issueType, data}) => {
                let IDs = data.data.map(row => row.id);
                return ({
                    url: `${issueType}/count`,
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: { IDs }
                })
            }
        })
```

Here is what I wish to achieve -

```
    let IDs = [];
    const { data, error, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetDataQuery();
    const { data: todoData, error: todoError } = useGetCountersQuery({"issueType": "todos", data: IDs}, {skip: IDs.length <= 0});
    const { data: rmaData, error: rmaError } = useGetCountersQuery({"issueType": "rmas", data: IDs}, {skip: IDs.length <= 0});


    if (error) { console.log(error); }

    if (data) {
        if (!data.success){ 
            console.log("failed"); 
        }
        IDs = data.data.map(row => row.id);
    }
```

I have tried it multiple ways but I wish to know the ideal way to do it. Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via using useLazyQuery from RTK query instead of regular useQuery hooks with the help of useEffect. UseLazyQuery hooks are similar to useQuery, but the main difference is we can manually control when the data fetching occurs. That means the query doesn't trigger automatically whenever the component mount or render.

```
const { data, error, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetDataQuery();
const [triggerGetCountersTodo, { data: todoData, error: todoError }] =
  useLazyGetCountersQuery();
const [triggerGetCountersRma, { data: rmaData, error: rmaError }] =
  useLazyGetCountersQuery();

useEffect(() => {
  if (isSuccess && data) {

    const ids = data.data.map(row => row.id);
    if (ids.length) {
      triggerGetCountersTodo({ "issueType": "todos", data: ids });
      triggerGetCountersRma({ "issueType": "rmas", data: ids });
    }

  }
}, [data, isSuccess, triggerGetCountersTodo, triggerGetCountersRma]);
```